# error: sudo service apache2 start Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code

Tags: ssh, apache2, services, raspberrypi, nextcloud

after editing the file "/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf", I noticed that my site was running much slower, so I rewrote the file from 0 with this (htps:/gist.github.com/hephaestus9/2a8562137841c99a74cb) which should be the original file.
After that, the terminal, when launching the command "sudo service apache2 start", gave this error message "sudo service apache2 start
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

The responses:

[sudo systemctl status apache2.service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRtBx.png)

[journalctl -xe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sflgy.png)

[Thu Nov 11 19:32:41.267783 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3805:tid 3069919680] AH00489: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 19:32:41.268193 2021] [core:notice] [pid 3805:tid 3069919680] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 19:37:22.832792 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3805:tid 3069919680] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Nov 11 19:37:22.921654 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18157] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 19:37:22.922052 2021] [core:notice] [pid 18157] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 19:37:23.312354 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18157] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Nov 11 19:37:23.525320 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18197] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 19:37:23.525499 2021] [core:notice] [pid 18197] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 19:52:54.774236 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 18197] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Nov 11 19:52:56.127776 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22427] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 19:52:56.127971 2021] [core:notice] [pid 22427] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 19:54:23.293572 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22427] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Nov 11 19:54:27.337261 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22591] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 19:54:27.337459 2021] [core:notice] [pid 22591] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 20:00:44.260736 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 22591] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Nov 11 20:00:44.677286 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23256] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) OpenSSL/1.1.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 20:00:44.677486 2021] [core:notice] [pid 23256] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:18.868009 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23256] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:19.117435 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 23256] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:19.117854 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23256] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) OpenSSL/1.1.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:19.117876 2021] [core:notice] [pid 23256] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:24.116080 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23256] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:24.264406 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 23387] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:24.423592 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 23388] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:24.449616 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23388] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) OpenSSL/1.1.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 20:02:24.449738 2021] [core:notice] [pid 23388] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 20:05:30.097019 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23388] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Nov 11 20:05:30.297607 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 23605] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Nov 11 20:05:30.460939 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 23606] AH01909: 127.0.1.1:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Thu Nov 11 20:05:30.488256 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23606] AH00163: Apache/2.4.51 (Raspbian) OpenSSL/1.1.1k configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Nov 11 20:05:30.488373 2021] [core:notice] [pid 23606] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Nov 11 22:21:15.867367 2021] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23606] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Comment: Please format your log excerpt as code. As it stands now, it is very hard to read.

Comment: Also, the output looks very strange for a Ubuntu system. Which Ubuntu version is this?

Comment: its raspbian os

Comment: Then you are in the wrong place. Ask Ubuntu is, as the name says, for Ubuntu. (Though my answer also holds for other Linux flavors.)

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot with the response from `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` shows the error message:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 14 >
Invalid command 'WSGIScriptAlias'>
```

(You'll have to scroll left to see the remainder of the message.)
This tells you that you've got a syntax error in your Apache configuration.
It even tells you precisely where the error is.
You just have to fix that error and Apache will start again.

Comment: I edited the original text with the response of the file you asked me.

Comment: where i can find the file?

Comment: For Raspbian I don't know, but scrolling to the right in `sudo systemctl status apache2.service` should reveal the file path.